# CF ORM many-to-many relationship sort order

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldbox

I have a many to many relationship setup, and need to control the order.

I have an entity with the property below. How do I control the order of the components when retrieved via this relationship?

```
property name="Components" fieldtype="many-to-many" cfc="CmsComponent" 
      type="array" 
      singularname="Component" 
      linktable="CMSPageComponents" 
      fkcolumn="page_id" 
      inversejoincolumn="component_id";
```

I've setup a column in the linktable (CMSPageComponents) called `dispOrder`. But when I set the `orderby="dispOrder"` or `orderby="CMSPageComponents.dispOrder"` attribute on the property above, it just seems to ignore it.

Any suggestions on how I can control the order of a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: AFAIK many-to-many is actually not too widely used and quite limited.  Try turning it into a one-to-many and sort order should be well supported.

Comment: Yes, one-to-many does have sorting quite easy, but I need a many-to-many.  one-to-many just doesn't give me the functionality I need.

Comment: What functionality? A many-to-many is basically just a pair of one-to-many relationships. If you want orderby with a column on the linktable, afaik promoting it to an entity is what you need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the relationship is many-to-many CF will apply the `orderBy` statement to the object table not to the link table. So in theory you could move your **dispOrder** column from the **CMSPageComponents** link table to the **CmsComponent** table to make it work.

But in practice I expect the ordering is specific to the many-to-many relationship (i.e. the particular page), in which case you could follow Peter's advice and create a separate entity which links the other two entities and lets you define an order property.

So you would have 3 entities:

1. CmsPage
2. CmsComponent
3. CmsPageComponent

**CmsPageComponent** might look something like this:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="CmsPageComponent" persistent="true" table="cmsPageComponents">
    <!--- Add a primary key for the link Entity --->
    <cfproperty name="ID" fieldType="id" generator="native">
    <cfproperty name="dispOrder">
    <cfproperty name="page" fieldType="many-to-one" cfc="CmsPage" fkColumn="pageID">
    <cfproperty name="component" fieldType="many-to-one" cfc="CmsComponent" fkColumn="componentID">
    <!--- init() etc --->
</cfcomponent>
```

**CmsPage** could then have a one-to-many relationship with the link entity allowing ordering using the dispOrder column:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="CmsPage" persistent="true" table="cmsPages">
    <cfproperty name="ID" fieldType="id" generator="native">
    <cfproperty name="pageComponents" singularName="pageComponent" fieldType="one-to-many" cfc="PageComponent" fkColumn="pageID" orderBy="dispOrder">
    <!--- init() etc --->
</cfcomponent>
```

**Update**
The following shows how you might add and display page components. Not the only or necessarily best way, but just to give you an idea:

```
<cfscript>
transaction{
    //load the page
    page    =   EntityLoadByPK( "CmsPage",1 );
    //load the components we want to add
    component1  =   EntityLoadByPK( "CmsComponent",1 );
    component2  =   EntityLoadByPK( "CmsComponent",2 );
    //create link objects
    pageComponent1  =   EntityNew( "CmsPageComponent" );
    pageComponent2  =   EntityNew( "CmsPageComponent" );
    // link them to the pages and components in the order we want
    pageComponent1.setComponent( component1 );
    pageComponent1.setPage( page );
    pageComponent1.setDispOrder( 2 );
    EntitySave( pageComponent1 );
    pageComponent2.setComponent( component2 );
    pageComponent2.setPage( page );
    pageComponent2.setDispOrder( 1 );
    EntitySave( pageComponent2 );
}
//Reload from the database so the order is applied
EntityReload( page );
</cfscript>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <cfoutput>
        <h2>Page #page.getID()#</h2>
        <ol>
            <cfloop array="#page.getPageComponents()#" index="pageComponent">
                <cfset component    =   pageComponent.getComponent()>
                <li>Component ID #component.getID()#, Display Order = #pageComponent.getDispOrder()#)</li>
            </cfloop>
        </ol>
    </cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: this assumes the ORM setting `flushAtRequestEnd` is true in Application.cfc

Comment: Thanks CFSimplicity!! Thanks to your explanation I think I understand what Peter was getting at now.  But I still can't see how this can emulate a many-to-many.  I can't think how I would add a component to a page, or get a list of components without it becoming a convoluted process?  Am I better of just reverting to a standard SQL Query to retreive components with current many-to-many setup?  Than you again!

Comment: I've added more code to my example to show you could add and display components using the intermediate object relationship. It is a more convoluted for sure, but does give you more flexibility as well as working around the CF limitation on ordering many-to-many.

Comment: Thank you CfSimplicity!  That worked a treat.  I actually thought it would get messy to implement, but in the end, not much more to it than just setting up a many-to-many.  THanks!